# Is it beneficial to create your own index based off of two combined keys instead of using those keys

Tags: database, postgresql, data-analysis, olap

Say I have a newspaper.
That newspaper sells ads from various providers across various sections of the paper (business, food, etc).

Now, say that I gather metrics on clicks, etc for each ad and store that in an oltp type database. I then crunch the data to get the number of clicks, etc for each ad type in each section.

I can have an OLAP database with fields as such ...

```
id, adProviderId, paperSectionId, data
```

I could put indexes on adProviderID and paperSectionId so that I can look them up quickly.

Is there any benefit to creating a column named combinedId whose contents were the combination of adProviderId and paperSectionId? This way, I could only have one key?

Would it be any different if I had a scenario where I had a dozen or so columns requiring keys in my OLAP?

How/Should I transition this to a columnar database?

Comment: Honestly, it would be worse. On any search you could just instead query to check for the existence of both adProviderId and paperSectionId in this database. Even if you wanted to make this a unique key, most columnar databases if not all can support multiple tuples as a single key.

Comment: What about in a noncolumnar database?